# listview isn't filling through asynctask

Tags: android, tabs, android-asynctask

i'm currently trying to fill my listview with AsyncTask.

**UPDATE**:
**I updated my codes as following:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    new loadSomeStuff(this.getActivity()).execute();

}

public static class loadSomeStuff extends
            AsyncTask<FragmentActivity, Integer, String> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;
        ArrayList<BeanClass4> beanClass4 = new ArrayList<BeanClass4>();
        SharedPreferences prefs;
        public static final String prefName = "SecretFile";
        FragmentActivity activity;

        public loadSomeStuff(FragmentActivity activity2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.activity = activity2;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setMessage("hi");
            dialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(FragmentActivity... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            beanClass4.clear();
            String result = "";
            InputStream isr = null;
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String url = "";
                HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpResponse resposne = httpclient.execute(httpost);
                HttpEntity entity = resposne.getEntity();
                isr = entity.getContent();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_httpconnection",
                        "error in http connection" + e.toString());
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(isr, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                isr.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_json", "Error converting Result " + e.toString());
            }
            try {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    beanClass4.add(new BeanClass4(json.getString("PhoneName"),
                            json.getString("ModelNumber"), json
                                    .getString("PhonePrice"), json
                                    .getString("imageurl"), json
                                    .getString("moneyunit"), json
                                    .getString("newphone")));
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("lag_tag", "ERROR PARSING DATA" + e.toString());
                beanClass4.clear();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            listview.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter4(activity, beanClass4));
            if (beanClass4.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "No Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

        }

    }
```

However, now when i open my activity. I see a progressdialog saying hi, then after 2~3 seconds i got this on logcat:

```
07-23 13:18:55.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1230): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 13:18:55.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1230): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-23 13:18:55.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at com.androidarabia.utils.Taby$loadSomeStuff.onPostExecute(Taby.java:268)
07-23 13:18:55.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at com.androidarabia.utils.Taby$loadSomeStuff.onPostExecute(Taby.java:1)
07-23 13:18:55.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
07-23 13:18:55.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-23 13:18:55.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
07-23 13:18:55.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 13:18:55.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-23 13:18:55.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
07-23 13:18:55.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 13:18:55.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-23 13:18:55.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-23 13:18:55.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-23 13:18:55.236: E/AndroidRuntime(1230):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What do do? YOUR HELP WILL BE MUCH MUCH APPRECIATED!

Comment: You need to post the logcat or any stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Also, post the code for class `MyListAdapter4`.

Comment: i'm highly sure that mylistadapter have no errors at all =)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're never calling the actual execute() method on AsyncTask... You only call your own version of it, which just stores the activity reverence and doesn't call super.execute(). Actually, overloading the execute method like that is bad design in my mind; I'd recommend creating a constructor in your LoadSomeStuff class that takes in and stores the reference to the activity. That way, your code in ArrayListFragment.onActivityCreated can just call execute() without a parameter.

I haven't really followed the rest of your code, so there might be other issues too, I don't know. But fix this first.

Comment: i didn't understand you, can you tell me what you mean in codes?

Comment: Ok, it looks like you're on the right track - your updated code looks exactly like what I suggested. Now you just have some small problem in onPostExecute - something is null. But I don't have your line numbers, so I don't know which line is 268. The stack trace for the NullPointerException says you have a problem on line 268. So check what's there, figure out what's null and why. The rest of it is looking good.

Answer (score 0):

your execute method  is an overload method not an override method .call your execute method doest not do anything except init your activity variable ,  it does not mean to call the execute method from AsynTask class:
you can change your method as a constructor :

```
     public LoadSomeStuff(FragmentActivity activity) {
                this.activity = activity;
            }
```

and in your activity :

```
            @Override
                public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                    new loadSomeStuff().execute(this.getActivity());

                }

            to :  
            new loadSomeStuff(this.getActivity()).execute();
```

or you can make your class :

```
 LoadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<FragmentActivity, Progress, Result>{
```

remove your execute method and call  :

new loadSomeStuff().execute(this.getActivity());

Hope this help :)

Comment: listview.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter4(activity, beanClass4));
it said the listview is null

Comment: Yes but the listview isnt null i think activity is null? plz help =(

Comment: well,I'm sure that your listview is null, where is your view inflated ? e.g.: listview=(ListView)convertView.findViewById ...